# IBM MobileFirst Platform 7.0 - SQL Adapter deployment failure in remote server

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-adapters

I have a simple SQL adapter, in a simple helloWorld application. All this app does is read a row from the database table and display it on the homepage. It works fine, deploys successfully in my local development server  and I can see the data on my app homepage preview. However, when I try to deploy the adapter in a remote MobileFirst Server from the MobileFirst Console by uploading the ‘.adapter' file, it gives me the error:

> FWLSE3064E: The "xml" file is missing

I have not been able to find what this error actually means and how can I fix it.

messages.log: http://pastebin.com/LqyRqid6
server.xml: http://pastebin.com/ZZy6Zkkv

Comment: To further debug the issue, upload the full messages.log file from the remote server.

Comment: Its a long error message, have edited the original message and pasted the actual error from the 'messages.log' file. I hope it gives a better insight to the problem.

Comment: Thanks, but I asked for the full messages.log file and not for an abbreviated version of it. Could you please upload the file as requested? Would also help to see your server.xml and well as information on the used application server - WAS/Liberty/Tomcat (full build number), Java version etc...

Comment: its Liberty WebSphere Application Server 8.5.5.4 and 
java.version = 1.7.0. The file itself is 4Mb, wasnt able to paste and share through pastebin either, any suggestion on how to upload that file so you can view it?

Comment: You can use Dropbox, Google Drive, Mega and the like to host the messages.log and server.xml files. Also, what is the MobileFirst version (number + full build number).

Comment: Hey, restarted the server to make sure old log is deleted and the log file is smaller now. Here is the messages.log file (http://pastebin.com/LqyRqid6), and the server.xml(http://pastebin.com/ZZy6Zkkv). MobileFirst version = MobileFirst Platform Studio 7.0.0.00-20150312-0731. Hope this helps

Comment: Two things: 1) upload the .adapter file. 2) Enable tracing: `<logging
traceSpecification="com.ibm.worklight*=all:com.worklight*=all"
traceFileName="trace.log" maxFileSize="20" maxFiles="10"
traceFormat="BASIC"></logging>` and upload the trace.log file.

Comment: trace.log = http://pastebin.com/pdWkBziS
had to use google drive for the adapter file: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B4TeEqTAPtzbQVA2S041TkVidmM/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Any reason why you say you're running MFP 7.0.0.0, but the logs say you're running 6.2.0.01?

Comment: @A.K, Is the MobileFirst server and MobileFirst studio is the same version?

Comment: @dhineshsundar, no. The adapter is from 7.0 but the server is running 6.2.

Comment: @IdanAdar, This is the gap for the cause, I believe.

Answer (score 0):

The adapter you are trying to deploy is from MobileFirst Platform Foundation 7.0 (as can be seen in the supplied .adapter file), however the server version is Worklight 6.2.0.01 (as can be seen in the supplied messages.log), or at least the deployed project .war file.

[Update the server installation to run v7.0.0.0](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSHS8R_7.0.0/com.ibm.worklight.installconfig.doc/topics/c_install_config.html) as well (or deploy the correct .war file). I suspect the deployment will then pass.